# Volume charge distribution in terms of delta and Heaviside function for a line of charge distributed along the $x$-axis from $x=−a/2$ to $x=a/2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

What would be the form of volume charge distribution for a charge λ per unit length uniformly distributed along the x axis from x = −a=/2 to x = a/2

I started with this:P = AH(a/2 -r)(θ-pi/2)((θ)+(θ-pi)), H is the Heaviside function

Comment: Do you just need the expression? Perhaps you can show your own attempts first.

Comment: P = AH(a/2 -r)(θ-pi/2)((θ)+(θ-pi)), H is the Heaviside function. This is what I'm thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be

$$\rho(x,y,z)=\lambda \delta(y)\delta(z)\Big(\Theta(x+a/2)-\Theta(x-a/2)\Big),\tag{1}$$

where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function. The dimensions of the $\delta$ are the inverse of its argument's, i.e. $[\delta(f)]=[f]^{-1},$ and the Heaviside function has no dimensions. So

$$[\rho]=[\lambda][\delta(y)][\delta(z)]=\frac{C}{L}L^{-1}L^{-1}=\frac{C}{L^3},$$

as it should be. You can see that this analysis of dimensions is not satisfied in your attempt, as angles are dimensionless.